# jQuery equivalent of Flash animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, gallery

I would like to imitate the animation happening when switching from one page to another using the menu on the left of this example webpage. This is one of several projects that I am working on to prove JavaScript and associated libraries are capable of producing animations equivalent to Flash.

I can get a simple hide animation going with this but it doesn't quite look the same as the Flash version. It's almost like they've used some easing effect for the slide out and in. I can't seem to figure out the CSS with which to animate it in JavaScript. Any ideas on the CSS I should be looking at or know of any plugins that have already accomplished this style?

http://www.wix.com/flash-templates/artistic-choice

http://www.alphadesigns.com.au/stackoverflow/index.html (updated with opacity option)

Comment: Great, now just speed up the animation and you'll get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try animating `opacity`. Note that this doesn't work in IE<9, you'll have to use a filter and a custom animation if IE6-8 must be supported (see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html).

Comment: I have modified the code with the opacity option and as you can see it is closer :) but still not quite the same. I think what I see is at the end of the fade/slide out the element eases out in its left movements so that it just appears to fall backwards (like a zoom out). Like it was a photo thrown onto a stack of other photos below. Does that make sense?

Comment: I can't completely follow you, but I think both animations should start at the same time and should use some advanced easing functions - the [jQuery Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) probably has something fitting.